# Smalltalk tricky syntax

Tags: smalltalk

In an exam example they ask if the statement is valid, and if it is, what it returns:

> Object class superclass class class

I can't follow that many messages by my own. Please, help!

Comment: You can always run it and look at the result, right?

Comment: Trust me, i did. The problem is, they don't allow laptops in the classroom :) I was sure until now that i don't need to memorize that awful inheritance diagram. So i still hope i don't. It depends on explanation here :)

Comment: I never thought I would see the words "tricky syntax" and "Smalltalk" in the same sentence! Smalltalk has one of the simplest syntaxes I know, second only to Lisp(s) and Io.

Comment: Well.. For a hardware engineer "superclass class class" doesn't look simple. I am sorry :) besides, arithmetic where + may happen before * took a week of my life for homework...

Comment: It's not a tricky syntax, just a chain of message send. But it's a tricky question, and in my humble Smalltalker's opinion, a bad one. As Smalltalk code, it stinks. Who would write such chanting code? Anyone wanting to understand the underlying class/metaclass structure, but you would do that for your own in an INTERACTIVE manner, then throw it away. Without interaction it's just dead and ugly code. If the result is that you feel that Smalltalk is tricky, then it's a complete teaching failure!

Comment: @GregoryKornblum: the *semantics* may be tricky, but you didn't ask about the semantics, you asked about the *syntax*, and Smalltalk has one of the simplest syntaxes of all programming languages. In the code you posted there are exactly two syntactic elements: a class reference and 4 message sends. Message sends are always evaluated strictly left-to-right, this again much simpler than other languages, e.g. in Ruby `2 * 3 + 4` is evaluated left-to-right but `2 + 3 * 4` is not, so the evaluation order depends on the name of the message, which is not the case in Smalltalk.

Comment: Guys, thanks for explanations and support. At least i feel more confident now :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `Object` is the root of the type system, you just need to carefully follow the rules:

1. Every normal class `X` is an instance of its metaclass `X class`
2. Every metaclass `X class` is an instance of the normal class `Metaclass`.
3. The metaclass inheritance graph follows the regular object inheritance graph, except that while the root object inherits from `nil`, its metaclass inherits from `Class`.

So it would be:

```
|             Expression              |     Type     |
|-------------------------------------|--------------|
| Object                              | Object       |
| Object class                        | Object class |
| Object class superclass             | Class        |
| Object class superclass class       | Class class  |
| Object class superclass class class | Metaclass    |
```

In practice `Object` isn't the root, its parent `ProtoObject` is; so if the exam authors took that into consideration, the above would then end with `Metaclass class`.

Comment: Ohh.. It's that case when i understand each word separately, and barely anything together. So Object class returns Object class. Object class superclass returns Class. Class class returns Metaclass?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Sending the message `class` to anything that has a name ending with space followed by "class" will return `Metaclass`.

Comment: You mean, xxxxxx class class always returns Metaclass?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Correct, as long as xxxxxx is a name of a class. `3 class class`, for example, will return something like `SmallInteger class`.

Comment: @Oak, did you check your table?

Comment: @StephanEggermont Nope. If it's incorrect please comment/edit/downvote. But notice my note about `ProtoObject`.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting aspect of the expression

```
Object class
```

is that its answer is not a `Class` but a `Metaclass`.

The reason why `Object class` is not a `Class` is that `Metaclass` is not a subclass of `Class`. More importantly, `Object class` does not inherit the behavior defined in `Class`.

Of course, one could be tempted to say that under the same criterion `Object` would not be a `Class` either because it is not an instance of `Class` but of its metaclass (namely, `Object class`.) But this is just because of some technicalities (or implementation details, if you will.) The truth is that `Object` (and all other classes for this matter) inherit behavior from `Class`, and that's why we say that they are classes, they behave as instances of `Class` (which, interesting enough, has no instances at all.)

The way to achieve this property consists in enforcing the following equation

```
ProtoObject class superclass == Class
```

Thanks to this relationship the class side of `ProtoObject` inherits the (instance) behavior of `Class` (even though `Class` has no subclasses.)

Now, why then the expression

```
Object class superclass
```

makes sense? If the receiver of `superclass` is not even a class, should it understand the message `superclass`?

The answer is yes, not only classes but metaclasses have a `superclass`. And here, again, the reason has to do with the inherited behavior.

Every programmer expects that if class `A` inherits from `B`, then `A class` will inherit all the methods of the class side of `B`. In other words,

```
A class superclass == B class
```

or, equivalently,

```
A class superclass == A superclass class
```

Note however that this relationship doesn't hold for `A == ProtoObject`, as we saw above (`ProtoObject class superclass == Class`.)

So, in the presence of `ProtoObject`, the expression

```
Object class superclass class class
```

becomes

```
Object superclass class class class
```

or

```
ProtoObject class class class
```

or

```
Metaclass class
```

because `ProtoObject class` is an instance of `Metaclass` and so its `class` is `Metaclass`.

To complete the answer let's calculate

```
ProtoObject class superclass class class
```

In this case we get

```
Class class class
```

or

```
Metaclass
```